# How to move around a date picker created with UIKit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to create a Date Picker in Swiftui, but i need to do it in UIKit because I need the "minute Interval" thing, I created it, but I can not move around, is stuck in the same place on my screen.  How can i make this work ? Is there a SwiftUI solution ?

```
struct DatePickerUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding private var selection: Date

    private let range: ClosedRange<Date>?

    private var minimumDate: Date? {
         range?.lowerBound
    }

    private var maximumDate: Date? {
        range?.upperBound
    }

    private var minuteInterval: Int

    private let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    init(selection: Binding<Date>, in range: ClosedRange<Date>?, minuteInterval: Int = 1) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.range = range
        self.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        datePicker.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
        datePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate
        datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.changed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.date = selection

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> DatePickerUIKit.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(selection: $selection, in: range, minuteInterval: minuteInterval)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let selection: Binding<Date>
        private let range: ClosedRange<Date>?
        private let minuteInterval: Int

        init(selection: Binding<Date>, in range: ClosedRange<Date>? = nil, minuteInterval: Int = 1) {
            self.selection = selection
            self.range = range
            self.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
        }

        @objc func changed(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
            self.selection.wrappedValue = sender.date
        }
    }
}
```

```
  var body: some View {
        let minMaxRange = Date.now...Date.now
        VStack {
            Spacer()
        DatePickerUIKit(selection: $dateFrom,
                        in: minMaxRange, minuteInterval: 30)
         
        }
}
}
```

Here is a picture where is always located . [image: picture]

Comment: reduce the `.frame` of `DatePickerUIKit` it seems to be the whole screen

Comment: @loremipsum that was the problem, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Default `UIDatePicker` does not have intrinsic content size which is used by SwiftUI `UIViewRepresentable` to determine frame of view.

Here is possible approach to improve your views so it fits own size (w/o hardcoding)

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2 (red border is for testing, also removed spacer to show how date picker looks by itself)

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoUIDatePickerView: View {
    @State private var dateFrom: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        let minMaxRange = Date.now...Date.now
        VStack {
            DatePickerUIKit(selection: $dateFrom,
                            in: minMaxRange, minuteInterval: 30)
                .border(Color.red)                 // << for testing !!!
        }
    }
}

extension UIDatePicker {
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {   // << required !!
        // calculates minimal needed size
        sizeThatFits(.zero)
    }
}

struct DatePickerUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding private var selection: Date

    private let range: ClosedRange<Date>?

    private var minimumDate: Date? {
        range?.lowerBound
    }

    private var maximumDate: Date? {
        range?.upperBound
    }

    private var minuteInterval: Int

    init(selection: Binding<Date>, in range: ClosedRange<Date>?, minuteInterval: Int = 1) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.range = range
        self.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        datePicker.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
        datePicker.minimumDate = minimumDate
        datePicker.maximumDate = maximumDate

        // Next constrains are also required to avoid control hugging
        datePicker.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)  // << !!
        datePicker.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)  // << !!

        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.changed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        return datePicker
    }

    func updateUIView(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.date = selection
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> DatePickerUIKit.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(selection: $selection, in: range, minuteInterval: minuteInterval)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let selection: Binding<Date>
        private let range: ClosedRange<Date>?
        private let minuteInterval: Int

        init(selection: Binding<Date>, in range: ClosedRange<Date>? = nil, minuteInterval: Int = 1) {
            self.selection = selection
            self.range = range
            self.minuteInterval = minuteInterval
        }

        @objc func changed(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
            self.selection.wrappedValue = sender.date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am in a similar situation and have tried implementing this solution but it makes my view disappear. Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491934/how-to-use-nslayoutconstraints-in-uiviewrepresentable

Comment: Stumbled upon this after hours of struggle. This is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on "lorem ipsum" comment, I fixed it, finally.

```
let minMaxRange = Date.now...Date.now
DatePickerUIKit(selection: $dateFrom,in: minMaxRange, minuteInterval: 30)
.frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
```