# Determine UIViewRepresentable with a custom UIView size dynamically

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I have an issue when trying to convert a custom View that inherits from UIView into a SwiftUI view, the view takes the whole screen.
But it works pretty well if I inherit from UILabel instead of UIView.

**Note** This view is shown inside a `UIHostingController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChild(hostingVC)
        view.addSubview(hostingVC.view)
        hostingVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        hostingVC.view.backgroundColor = .red
        hostingVC.view.wh_activateConstraints(configuration: {
            [
                $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                $0.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                $0.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            ]
        })
    }
    
    
}
```

Example 1:
this will work

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomLabel()
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
struct CustomLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.text =  "hello world"
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }
}
```

Example 2: this will not work

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomLabel()
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}


struct CustomLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = CustomUIlabel()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }
}


class CustomUIlabel: UIView {
    init(){
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.text =  "hello world"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
            ]
        )
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And when adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` for second example the custom view will disappear.
and If I comment it, the view will take the whole screen.

Is there any solution to determine the size dynamically of a custom view that inherits from UIView?

Comment: Your custom view should provide `intrinsicContentSize` returning value size. This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/70684558/12299030.

Comment: it works If I set the intrinsicContentSize explicitly like 
`CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)`
But I need it to be more dynamic because my actual view has a lot of components not just UILabel